# How to Plot line using matlab and Radon Transformation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, line, transform

I used this code to detect lines from images using the Radon Transform function radon().

```
I = imread('C:\Users\AMiNE\Desktop\sequance 2\Daylight_00010.jpeg');
L=rgb2gray(I);
BW = edge(L);
imshow(I)
figure, imshow(BW)
theta = 0:179;
[R,xp] = radon(BW,theta);
figure, imagesc(theta, xp, R); colormap(hot);
xlabel('\theta (degrees)'); ylabel('X\prime');
title('R_{\theta} (X\prime)');
colorbar
```

Here support page from matlab web site [radon](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/radon-transform.html)!

And so far it works perfectly to plot the Radon Transform of an Edge Image

[image]

but I need to plot the lines in the source image " I " like they did in the link below step 3

Comment: Could you better explain what you need that's different from what you have?  What have you tried?
Not everyone is willing to go read the site you linked to figure out how to help you.  If you could copy the relevant information into your question, it'd be helpful.

Comment: Ok , well it's simple the web page is for line detection using radon ,it begin with loading image and finished by draw line lines in that image, well i have R,xp ,theta i need to draw line , this the result a get http://i57.tinypic.com/rhjyv9.jpg

Comment: I don't know matlab, but the site explains the theory pretty well: you need to find the "hot spots" in your transform.  Use some kind of a threshold to figure out those points and their x', theta.  For each of those points, theta is the angle of a line passing through the center point of your image.  x' is where the detected perpendicular line intersects that line.  In fact, I think you should be able to just solve the polar coordinate equation $(x+centerx)*cos(theta)+(y+centery)*sin(theta)=xp$ to find a point on your line, then use theta+90 degrees (or pi/2) to plot the rest of the line.